# Is the new Firefox Content Blocking similar to Ghostery?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, privacy, privacy-protection, ghostery

I have been using the Ghostery plugin with Firefox for a while now as my main tracking and ad blocker. I've noticed that the new Firefox 63 also has content blocking. Do I no longer need Ghostery because Firefox 63 effectively does the same thing?